# Using WLST to bounce a managed server?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

Is there a way to bounce/restart a managed server using WLST? The ServerRuntime MBean seems to have the correct functions to do this but as far as I can tell, you can only access this MBean for the server WLST is connected to ie the admin server. Is there a way to access this MBean for each Managed Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  I use it all the time in automated build / deployment tasks.

[Connect to the node manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/reference.htm#autoId349) and call [shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/reference.htm#autoId365) / [start](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/reference.htm#autoId381) for each managed server / cluster.

Comment: Example link is dead

Comment: I've removed the dead links that the last editor added.  They were links to his blog.